# Kubernetes component setup for Windows Server 2016

Tags: kubernetes, windows-server-2016, windows-container

I want to setup Kubernetes on Windows Server 2016. I have been following https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/ however I am getting validation errors when building the kubelet.exe and kube-proxy.exe.

I have cloned the kubernetes (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) repo to [GOPATH]\k82.io and then ran the "go build cmd/kube-proxy/proxy.go" command in powershell however I get these errors:

pkg\api\validation\validation.go:31:2: cannot find package "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/equality" in any of:        C:\gowork\src\k8s.io\kubernetes\vendor\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\equality (vendor tree)
        C:\Go\src\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\equality (from $GOROOT)
        C:\gowork\src\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\equality (from $GOPATH)

pkg\volume\util.go:35:2: cannot find package 
"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors" in any of:
C:\gowork\src\k8s.io\kubernetes\vendor\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\errors (vendor tree)
        C:\Go\src\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\errors (from $GOROOT)
        C:\gowork\src\k8s.io\apimachinery\pkg\api\errors (from $GOPATH)
...

Am I using the correct repo? 
Has anyone else managed to build a kubelet.exe and kube-proxy.exe for Windows Server 2016?

Comment: I'm wondering if you ever figured this out.  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build kubelet.exe and kube-proxy.exe by following steps in this tutorial: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/kubernetes-build-win-binaries.md

I was using ubuntu16.04 image on google compute engine